# Go Gorilla Mux MiddlewareFunc with r.Use and returning errors

Tags: go

How do you set up Gorilla Mux r.Use to return errors down the middleware chain? https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.Use

Main.go

```
r := mux.NewRouter()

r.Use(LoggingFunc)
r.Use(AuthFunc)
```

Basic middleware

Starts with logging middleware which can catch and handle errors from further down the chain

```
type HandlerFunc func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error

func LoggingFunc(next HandlerFunc) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Logging middleware

        defer func() {
            if err, ok := recover().(error); ok {
                w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            }
        }()

        err := next(w, r)
        if err != nil {
            // log error
        }
    })
}
```

The next middleware handles authentication and returns an error to the logging middleware.

```
func AuthFunc(next HandlerFunc) HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {

        if r.GET("JWT") == "" {
            return fmt.Errorf("No JWT")
        }

        return next(w, r)
    }
}
```

I keep getting errors like

```
  cannot use AuthFunc (type func(handlers.HandlerFunc) http.Handler) as type mux.MiddlewareFunc in argument to r.Use
```

Thanks

Comment: `AuthFunc` should return `http.Handler` and not `HandlerFunc` type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [mux.Use doc](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.Use) its argument type is [MiddlewareFunc](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#MiddlewareFunc) which return type is `http.Handler` not error type. You have to define which return type is `http.HandlerFunc`

```
type Middleware func(http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    //  execute middleware from right to left of the chain
    chain := Chain(SayHello, AuthFunc(), LoggingFunc())
    r.HandleFunc("/", chain)

    println("server listening :  8000")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r)
}

// Chain applies middlewares to a http.HandlerFunc
func Chain(f http.HandlerFunc, middlewares ...Middleware) http.HandlerFunc {
    for _, m := range middlewares {
        f = m(f)
    }
    return f
}

func LoggingFunc() Middleware {
    return func(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
        return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            // Loggin middleware

            defer func() {
                if _, ok := recover().(error); ok {
                    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
                }
            }()

            // Call next middleware/handler in chain
            next(w, r)
        }
    }
}

func AuthFunc() Middleware {
    return func(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
        return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

            if r.Header.Get("JWT") == "" {
                fmt.Errorf("No JWT")
                return
            }

            next(w, r)
        }
    }

}

func SayHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello client")
}
```

It will execute the `LogginFunc` then `AuthFunc` and then `SayHello` method which is your desire method after passing all those middlewares.